# Can't connect to port 8080 using TIDHttp

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

Using Delphi 11.

I have two http servers running on my machine ; one on 80 port and other on 8080 .

I can sucesfully use TIDHttp to connect on the 'regular' server on 80 port, like so :

```
idhttp1.get('localhost');
```

But when i try to do the same with the server on 8080 port :

```
idhttp1.get('localhost:8080');
```

It raises the excepction "Unknown Protocol".

I can connect on both server directly on Chrome using the same addresses. What am i missing , please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

After i posted the question, i figured out.

Instead of

```
idhttp1.get('localhost:8080');
```

I needed to use

```
idhttp1.get('http://localhost:8080');
```

Comment: You need to specify the `http://` or `https://` scheme on all requested URLs, even if there is no port specified. So `idhttp1.get('localhost')` should be `idhttp1.get('http://localhost')`, too